# bluetooth v4 transmitter paired with bluetooth v2.1 receiver compatible?

Tags: bluetooth

can a bluetooth v4 transmitter successfully be connected to a receiver with bluetooth v2.1? asking because I have a tablet with v2.1 and a BLE with v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of bluetooth are downward-complatible, see e.g. [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/588186/is-bluetooth-4-0-backwards-compatible-with-bluetooth-2-0edr#588189). [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Specifications_and_features) as well:

> All versions of the Bluetooth standards support downward compatibility.[1](https://superuser.com/questions/588186/is-bluetooth-4-0-backwards-compatible-with-bluetooth-2-0edr#588189) That lets the latest standard cover all older versions.

Therefore, your BLE device should be able to pair with your tablet.

However, keep in mind that only the features supported by the older version will work. So of course you won't be able to use BLE with your BT v2.1 tablet. Everything else should be fine, though.